# How to override the Robolectric runtime dependency repository URL?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

We're trying to use the `org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0` dependency from our own internal Nexus repository.  The issue is that Robolectric tries to load some dependencies at runtime from a public repository ([as mentioned here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/571)), and ignores any repository overrides in the build.gradle.

Since we don't have access to that public location from our intranet, my tests timeout after trying to load that dependency:

> [WARNING] Unable to get resource
>   'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1' from
>   repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/):
>   Error transferring file: Operation timed out

The bottom section of the [Robolectric configuration documentation](http://robolectric.org/configuring/) recommends adding this to your Gradle configuration to override the URL:

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
      systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.repo.url', 'https://local-mirror/repo'
      systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.repo.id', 'local'
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I've tested that and I never see that system property being set.  I've printed it out from inside my custom Robolectric runner (which extends `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`) and that system property remains set to null.

```
System.out.println("robolectric.dependency.repo.url: " + System.getProperty("robolectric.dependency.repo.url"));
```

I also tried to do something similar to [this comment](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/571#issuecomment-18950567) (but that method doesn't exist to override in `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`), and I also tried setting the system properties directly in my custom Robolectric runner, and that didn't seem to help.

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class CustomRobolectricRunner extends RobolectricGradleTestRunner {
    private static final String BUILD_OUTPUT = "build/intermediates";

    public CustomRobolectricRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);

        System.setProperty("robolectric.dependency.repo.url", "https://nexus.myinternaldomain.com/content");
        System.setProperty("robolectric.dependency.repo.id", "internal");

        System.out.println("robolectric.dependency.repo.url: " + System.getProperty("robolectric.dependency.repo.url"));
    }
```

The [Robolectric source code](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/78ef7facd8df6c2c2f8dafedfbc2d1af19f3558e/robolectric-resources/src/main/java/org/robolectric/RoboSettings.java) does seem to confirm that these system properties exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While not a fix for using the properties directly, another way to get this to work is by overriding `getJarResolver()` in a `RobolectricTestRunner` subclass and pointing it at your artifact host:

```
public final class MyTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
  public MyTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
    super(testClass);
  }

  @Override protected DependencyResolver getJarResolver() {
    return new CustomDependencyResolver();
  }

  static final class CustomDependencyResolver implements DependencyResolver {
    private final Project project = new Project();

    @Override public URL[] getLocalArtifactUrls(DependencyJar... dependencies) {
      DependenciesTask dependenciesTask = new DependenciesTask();
      RemoteRepository repository = new RemoteRepository();
      repository.setUrl("https://my-nexus.example.com/content/groups/public");
      repository.setId("my-nexus");
      dependenciesTask.addConfiguredRemoteRepository(repository);
      dependenciesTask.setProject(project);
      for (DependencyJar dependencyJar : dependencies) {
        Dependency dependency = new Dependency();
        dependency.setArtifactId(dependencyJar.getArtifactId());
        dependency.setGroupId(dependencyJar.getGroupId());
        dependency.setType(dependencyJar.getType());
        dependency.setVersion(dependencyJar.getVersion());
        if (dependencyJar.getClassifier() != null) {
          dependency.setClassifier(dependencyJar.getClassifier());
        }
        dependenciesTask.addDependency(dependency);
      }
      dependenciesTask.execute();

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Hashtable<String, String> artifacts = project.getProperties();
      URL[] urls = new URL[dependencies.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        try {
          urls[i] = Util.url(artifacts.get(key(dependencies[i])));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
      return urls;
    }

    @Override public URL getLocalArtifactUrl(DependencyJar dependency) {
      URL[] urls = getLocalArtifactUrls(dependency);
      if (urls.length > 0) {
        return urls[0];
      }
      return null;
    }

    private String key(DependencyJar dependency) {
      String key =
          dependency.getGroupId() + ":" + dependency.getArtifactId() + ":" + dependency.getType();
      if (dependency.getClassifier() != null) {
        key += ":" + dependency.getClassifier();
      }
      return key;
    }
  }
}
```

It should be noted that this relies on two internal classes of Robolectric so care should be taken when upgrading versions.

Answer (score 5):

You can set properties `mavenRepositoryId` and `mavenRepositoryUrl` of `RoboSettings` which are used by [`MavenDependencyResolver`](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/78ef7facd8df6c2c2f8dafedfbc2d1af19f3558e/robolectric/src/main/java/org/robolectric/internal/dependency/MavenDependencyResolver.java).

Example:

```
public class CustomRobolectricRunner extends RobolectricGradleTestRunner {

    static {
        RoboSettings.setMavenRepositoryId("my-nexus");
        RoboSettings.setMavenRepositoryUrl("https://my-nexus.example.com/content/groups/public");
    }


    ...
}
```

Comment: `RoboSettings` is deprecated and these methods no longer exist. I checked version 4.3.1

Comment: Hi @Alix. Please have a look at [MavenRoboSettings](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/plugins/maven-dependency-resolver/src/main/java/org/robolectric/MavenRoboSettings.java) which is deprecated as well but it should work for version 4.3.1.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work for me unfortunately. I start to wonder if it's because I use `@RunWith(AndroidJunit4.class)`... Don't have time to verify this right now

Answer (score 1):

As per the [linked Github issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/571), one fix is to configure a `settings.xml` in your `~\.m2` folder:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>JCenter Remote</name>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>https://www.example.com/artifactory/jcenter-remote/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

`<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` seems necessary to force Maven to redirect all repository requests to the one remote. See [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) for more details about mirror settings in Maven.

I found that using a remote of Sonatype is not sufficient, you should use a remote of JCenter or Maven Central in order to obtain all of the transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

As of time of this writing, those previous answers are now obsolete. If you refer to the latest [robolectric documentation](http://robolectric.org/configuring/) you need to override the `robolectric.dependency.repo.url` property like so:

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
      systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.repo.url', 'https://local-mirror/repo'
      systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.repo.id', 'local'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This exact solution and link are mentioned in the original question.

Comment: You're right. I was so focused on reading and trying the different answers I had missed that part in the original question. My apologies. Weirldy enough tough, this is really the only thing that worked for me.